# Looping through results returns empty string for NULL values?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

If I have NULL values in my database and pull them into an array, I get empty strings. For example:

```
$test = [];
while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $test[$row['id']]['field1'] = $row['field1'];
    $test[$row['id']]['field2'] = $row['field2']; // null in database
    $test[$row['id']]['field3'] = null; // explicitly set to null
}
return $test;
```

Outputs:

```
array(1) {
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["field1"]=>
    string(4) "test"
    ["field2"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["field3"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
}
```

I'm just trying to understand why I end up with empty strings rather than NULL values? Am I doing something wrong or is this the way it's supposed to work?

Comment: How are you outputting that `$test` array?  What is happening to it between returning it and outputting it?

Comment: Example: http://pastebin.com/2t7F2ALu

Answer (score 1):

PDO does not automatically retrieve native MySQL data types.  In order to do so, you must use prepared statements and must be running PHP 5.3 (provided your version of PHP 5.3 is compiled with mysqlnd (and not the old libmysql)).

Also, you must establish your connection like this:

```
$conn = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, array(
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false
));
```

PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES enables or disables emulation of prepared statements.

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php

In order to see the actual NULL value, you need to do a [var_dump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) or check to see if the value is null by using `is_null`.

Comment: I am using prepared statements, and I'm running PHP Version 5.4.12-1~oneiric+1.

Comment: Compiled with mysqlnd?

Comment: I don't see libmysql or mysqlnd in my phpinfo, just mysqld.sock. Regardless, even if I explicitly set a value to null as in my example, it still returns an empty string, which would suggest this isn't necessarily related specifically to PDO wouldn't it?

Comment: This works fine for me:

<?php

$value = NULL;

var_dump($value);

?>

Comment: My browser outputs: NULL

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ORACLE_NULLS, PDO::NULL_NATURAL );
```

`PDO::NULL_NATURAL`: No conversion.

Comment: No change. Again, I'd like to point out in my example that I am explicitly setting a value to NULL, regardless of what PDO returns. It is still an empty string.